# apache server in lubuntu is not responding to port-forwarding in router

Tags: lubuntu, apache2, router, port-forwarding

apache server in lubuntu is not responding to port-forwarding  in router i tried a lot to make apache server to make it repond to port-forwarding  like changing the settings of ufw and apache sever  its not working with public ip address from outside network or internet it is working inside the home network

Comment: This is not on topic, as this is a networking or configuration issue with your device. I am sure there are forums or other locations that can go into more detail about the requirements (once provided more information such as ports, router etc.) - but alas, not here.

Comment: You have not given us enough information to help. However, if your acpahe server is working on your LAN, then your issue is with either with the port forwarding not working properly OR your listen directive in your apache configuration is restrictiing access.

Comment: Apache is working in my lan but not working with public ip address @DougSmythies